# React app with paging

Tags: react.js, url-routing, pagination, jsx

I want to create react app with paging, which will keep state on page reloading.
I'm using `react-router-dom` and my own `Paging` component.
Currently I'm passing `updateRoute` function into `SmthWithPaging` component.

Is there simpler (or just correct?) way to update route inside component?

Surely, I can do it inside `SmthWithPaging` component by spliting path by `/`, replace the number and push new path to history. But in this case child component will have some knowlege about parent component and how its routing works. Which is undesirable.

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route}  from 'react-router-dom';
import SmthWithPaging from './SmthWithPaging.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route
          path='page/:number'
          render={ ({history, match}) => (
            <SmthWithPaging
              currentPage={match.params.number}
              updateRoute={number =>
                history.push(match.path.replace(':number', number))}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Router >
    );
  }
}
```

**SmthWithPaging.js**

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
import Paging from './Paging.js';

class SmthWithPaging extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {currentPage: props.currentPage};
    this.updateRoute = props.updateRoute;
    this._handlePageChange = this._handlePageChange.bind(this);
  }

  async _handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.updateRoute(pageNumber);
    //fetch some data related to the page and set it to the state
    this.setState({currentPage: pageNumber});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      //render some page related data
      <Paging
        onPageChange={this._handlePageChange}
        activePage={this.state.currentPage}
        pageCount={10}
      />
    );
  }
}
```